# Windows 7 stops when holding a key

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I hold down a key on my keyboard, my Windows 7 laptop goes all wonky.  Graphics freeze and don't update until I release the key, and any audio starts repeating the last sound that it was playing.  I'd love to give more information about the problem, but I don't know where to start with this one. I'm happy to answer any more questions you may have.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's with a particular key or every key??

Comment: It happens with every key.

Comment: How long do you have to hold the key down before it happens?

Comment: It happens within a fraction of a second, and sometimes is even noticeable with key presses at normal typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the solution: if you have any of the Windows Sound Enhancements, disable them. It worked for me. Any software that you're using might be the cause. For instance, my sound gets choppy if I set an equalization preset with the IDT PC Audio software that came with my Dell laptop.